Generate eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr class based ros IDL generated std_msgs::msg::ByteMultiArray msg files instead of eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr
I am trying to improve the performance for large data transfer through ros2-humble framework (FastDDS 2.6.7, FastCDR 1.0.24). by analyzing the workflow, I found the following observations

The c++ std vector resize() operation that used in cdr class in
FastCDR library took more time than a normal malloc operation.
In ROS2 - humble the IDL files generated for
std_msgs::msg::ByteMultiArray type use the eprosima::fastcdr::Cdr
class and this class uses std::vector for memmory management. and
eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr has the functions that using
malloc operations for the memory allocation. So I assume switching
to FastCdr class will help to reduce the delay.

Queries.
Is the FastCdr class is fully developed for ros2 humble?
Is the std_msgs::msg::ByteMultiArray type not supported by the FastCdr class?
However, I would also like to be able to generate code for those same IDL files but that use eprosima::fastcdr::FastCdr class instead.
